# Success function not being called after making AJAX request codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

When I make an AJAX call from view and pass form data to the controller. I get a couple of problems. First, the code inside success is never executed, and second, the page is being refreshed even though it is an AJAX call. Can anyone tell me where am I doing wrong?

I have seen a lot of questions since yesterday but none of them were able to solve my problem.

Model code

```
public function insert_user($name, $email) {
    $data = array();
    $data['name'] = $name;
    $data['email'] = $email;
    $data['created_at'] = date('y-m-d');

    $this->db->insert('all_users', $data);
    return true;
}
```

Controller code

```
public function insert_user () {
    $data = $this->input->post();
    $name = $data['name'];
    $email = $data['email'];
    $this->User_model->insert_user($name, $email);
    $this->load->view('view');
}
```

Ajax request code

```
const insertBtn = $(".insert-btn");
insertBtn.on("click", function () {
                const name = $(".insert-form input[type=name]");
                const email = $(".insert-form input[type=email]");
                $.ajax({
                   url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Users/insert_user",
                   type: "post",
                   data: {name, email},
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function () {
                       $("body").append("Request made successfully");
                   } 
                })
            });
```

My form looks something like this:

```
<form class="insert-form" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Users/insert_user" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter name">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        <button class="insert-btn">Insert Data</button>
    </form>
```

NOTE: I am able to successfully insert data into the database.

Comment: What is in your `$this->load->view('view');` view file?  Is it JSON data?  Your `dataType: "json",` is telling jQuery it is.  Try removing `dataType: "json",` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: view contains the ajax code that gets the input values from a form. I am getting the data accurately

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `dataType: "json",` line?

Comment: How are you submitting your form, are you clicking the button or hitting enter?

Comment: No it doesn't works that way. Also I have made a mistake in getting the data in jQuery but even that doesn't solves the problem.
I am clicking the button to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

The browser is submitting the form before your AJAX code gets a chance to run/finish.

Instead of binding an event to the `click` event of the button, you want to bind to the `submit` event of the form.  Then you want to cancel the browser's default action.  This is done via the `e.preventDefault();` method.

Also, `dataType: "json"` is not needed here.  `dataType` tells jQuery what kind of data your AJAX call is returning.  You generally don't need it as jQuery can automatically detect it.  Plus, if you are not returning a JSON document, then this may cause a problem.

```
const insertForm = $(".insert-form");
insertForm.on("submit", function (e) {
    const name = insertForm.find("input[type=name]");
    const email = insertForm.find("input[type=email]");

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Users/insert_user",
        type: "post",
        data: {name, email},
        success: function () {
            $("body").append("Request made successfully");
        } 
    })
});
```

Comment: But the page still keeps on refreshing even after changing the code.

Comment: Did you add the `e.preventDefault();` line?  That's supposed to prevent that.

Comment: One more thing. If I comment out my script containing ajax request the code still works. Meaning that the data is still being inserted to the database.

Comment: Yes, because the browser is submitting your form.  That's what the `action=` and `method=` does.  This happens before the AJAX code is able to run.  `e.preventDefault();` tells the browser not to submit the form itself.

Comment: @ArunBohra How are you running this code?  Is it inside a `$(function(){})` block or something?  It's possible this event isn't being bound and this code is never running.

Comment: @ArunBohra Here's a small demo of what I am trying to show: https://jsfiddle.net/rj3wq6z7/

Comment: No the code is running because I can see the console.log before the ajax request but the log after ajax request is not printing anything.

Comment: @ArunBohra the problem is in your controller, you should echo the view back to the ajax call and then do something with it in the DOM. Read https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/loader.html?#CI_Loader::view, use `true` for return parameter

Comment: @Vickel `$this->load->view('view');` should echo the view to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Controller code

```
public function insert_user () {
    $data = $this->input->post();
    $name = $data['name'];
    $email = $data['email'];
    $data = $this->User_model->insert_user($name, $email);
    $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode($data));
}
```

Comment: I suppose this is meant to continue your other answer and not meant to be a stand alone answer? If, so please delete this and add the context to the other answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ajax request code

```
const insertBtn = $(".insert-btn");
insertBtn.on("click", function () {
                const name = $(".insert-form input[type=name]");
                const email = $(".insert-form input[type=email]");
                $.ajax({
                   url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>Users/insert_user", // <?php echo base_url() ?>controller_name/function_name
                   type: "post",
                   data: {name, email},
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function () {
                       $("body").append("Request made successfully");
                   } 
                })
            });
```

form looks something like this:

```
<form class="insert-form"  method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter name">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        <button class="insert-btn">Insert Data</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: The correct form should be the one with the input of type button which doesn't submits the form.

Answer (score 0):

The page was being refreshed because I had a button that was acting as submit button on changing it to the input of the type button it does not submits the form and we don't see the page being refreshed. And also the AJAX request made also runs successfully.

```
<form class="insert-form" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Users/insert_user" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter name">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        <input type="button" class="insert-btn" value="Insert Data">
</form>
```